# Turn treeview tkinter inserted data into a dataframe to turn it into matplotlib chart

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a problem with this code: I keep trying to turn the inserted data treeview tkinter to dataframe to a matplotlib chart, but it doesn't work. What went wrong?

```
#create a function for the insert data button
def insert_data():
    from tkinter import messagebox
    year = year_button.get()
    month = month_button.get()
    product_categories = product_categories_button.get()
    dc_options = dc_options_button.get()
    actual_data = int(actual_spinbox.get())
    forecast_data = int(forecast_spinbox.get())
    accuracy = (((forecast_data - actual_data) / actual_data) * 100 )
    messagebox.askyesno("Confirmation", "Do You Want to Input this Data?")
    value = year, month, product_categories, dc_options, forecast_data, actual_data, accuracy
    forecast_table.insert("", index='end', values=value)
    return accuracy

#create a function to option of show forecast accuracy chart for 2023
row_list = []
column = ('year', 'month', 'product_categories', 'dc_options', 'forecast_data', 'actual_data', 'accuracy')
for child in forecast_table.get_children():
    row_list.append([forecast_table.item(child)['values']])
forecast_table_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=column)

#create a multi-condition filter to show the forecast accuracy chart for year 2023, dc place = pondok ungu
filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2023_pondok_ungu = forecast_table_dataframe.loc[(forecast_table_dataframe['year'] == 2023) & (forecast_table_dataframe['dc_options']=='Pondok Ungu')]

#create a graph for forecasta accuracy chart year 2023, dc place pondok ungu: Forecast Accuracy in Each Month for Each Product Categories in 2023
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_xlabel('Month')
ax1.set_ylabel('Forecast Accuracy')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
ax1.set_title("Forecast Accuracy in Each Month for Each Product Categories in 2023")
ax1.plot(filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2023_pondok_ungu['month'], filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2023_pondok_ungu['accuracy'], label='Accuracy')
ax1.plot(filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2023_pondok_ungu['month'], filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2023_pondok_ungu['product_categories'], label= 'Product Categories')
ax1.legend()

#create a graph for forecast accuracy chart year 2023, dc place pondok ungu: Actual vs Forecast Data for Each Month in 2023
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.set_xlabel('Month')
ax2.set_ylabel('Actual Data')
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
ax2.plot(filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2023_pondok_ungu['month'], filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2023_pondok_ungu['actual_data'], label='Actual Data')
ax2.plot(filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2023_pondok_ungu['month'], filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2023_pondok_ungu['forecast_data'], label='Forecast Data')
ax2.legend()
ax2.set_title('Actual vs Forecast Data for Each Month in 2023')

#create a multi-condition filter to show the forecast accuracy chart for year 2024, dc place = pondok ungu
filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2024_pondok_ungu = forecast_table_dataframe.loc[(forecast_table_dataframe['year'] == 2024) & (forecast_table_dataframe['dc_options'] == 'Pondok Ungu')]

#create a graph for forecast accuracy chart year 2023, dc place pondok ungu: Actual vs Forecast Data for Each Month in 2024
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.set_xlabel('Month')
ax3.set_ylabel('Actual Data')
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
ax3.plot(filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2024_pondok_ungu['month'], filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2024_pondok_ungu['actual_data'], label='Actual Data')
ax3.plot(filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2024_pondok_ungu['month'], filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2024_pondok_ungu['forecast_data'], label='Forecast Data')
ax3.legend()
ax3.set_title('Actual vs Forecast Data for Each Month in 2024')

#create a graph for forecasta accuracy chart year 2024, dc place pondok ungu: Forecast Accuracy in Each Month for Each Product Categories in 2023
fig4, ax4 = plt.subplots()
ax4.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
ax4.set_xlabel('Month')
ax4.set_ylabel('Forecast Accuracy')
ax4.set_title("Forecast Accuracy in Each Month for Each Product Categories in 2024")
ax4.plot(filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2024_pondok_ungu['month'], filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2024_pondok_ungu['forecast_data'], label='Forecast Data')
ax4.plot(filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2024_pondok_ungu['month'], filtered_forecast_table_dataframe_2024_pondok_ungu['product_categories'], label='Product Categories')
ax4.legend()
```

I tried changing the treeview tkinter to a dataframe, then filtered it to year '2023' and '2024' and dc_options = 'pondok ungu', but when i try to click the forecast chart button, there is no line in chart.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zayRt.png)

Comment: Post a [mre] and debugging details.

Comment: the debugging details that i got is that "This evaluation is really slow and this is expected.
    In this case it's possible to silence this error by raising the timeout, setting the
    PYDEVD_WARN_EVALUATION_TIMEOUT environment variable to a bigger value."

Comment: By "debugging details", I mean you need to do a preliminary debugging. Did you print arguments of calls for the ```plot()```?